# Solving a (simple) numeric exercise in bash

Tags: bash, math

Some of you are probably familiar with Project Euler, and I'm currently attempting a few of their problems to teach myself some more bash. They're a bit more mathematical than 'script-y' but it helps with syntax etc.

The problem currently asks me to solve:

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

The code I have looks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

i="1"

for i in `seq 1 333`
do
    threes[$i]=`calc $i*3` # where 'calc' is a function written in bashrc
    #calc actually looks like: calc() {awk "BEGIN { print "$*"} }

    let "sumthrees = sumthrees + ${threes[$i]}"
done

for i in `seq 1 199`
do
    fives[$i]=`calc $i*5`
    let "sumfives = sumfives + ${fives[$i]}"
done

let "ans = $sumfives + $sumthrees"

echo "The sum of all 3 factors is $sumthrees and the sum of all five factors is $sumfives"
echo "The sum of both is $ans"

#So I can repeatedly run the script without bash remembering the variables between executions
unset i
unset fives
unset threes
unset sumfives
unset sumthrees
unset ans
```

So far I've not gotten the correct answer, but have run out of ideas as to where I'm going wrong. (FYI, the script currently gives me 266333, which I believe is close, but I don't know the answer yet.)

Can anyone spot anything? And for my own learning, if there are more elegant solutions to this that people might like to share that would be great.

**EDIT**

Thanks for all the answers, super informative. Since there are so many useful answers here I'll accept my favourite as the proper thread answer.

Comment: The `unset` operations are really not necessary.  You should set the variables to 0 at the outset.  Unless you run the script with `.` (aka `source`), which would be an eccentric way of testing a script, the variables will go out of existence when the shell exits.

Comment: I was sourcing it, I didn't know it would have that effect however :P thanks

Comment: OK; don't test scripts by sourcing them.  In fact, don't source scripts in general.  Only source scripts when you want the script to set properties of the current shell — current directory, environment variables (or ordinary variables), file descriptors, etc.  Generally, use `bash -x script` to execute the script with debugging enabled; drop the `-x` when you don't need to see what is happening while it happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Blue Moon pointed out the actual problem with your logic.
- You don't need to store all the threes and fives in arrays because you don't need them later.
- You don't need to unset variables at the end of a script if you use `./yourscript` or `bash script` because they'll disappear along with the 
  shell instance (better to initialize them first in any case).
- You don't need `awk` to do math, `bash` does that just fine.
- `seq` and `let` are not the best way to do anything in a bash script.

Here's a straight forward version:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum=0
for ((i=1; i<1000; i++))
do
  if (( i%3 == 0 || i%5 == 0 ))
  then
    (( sum += i ))
  fi
done
echo "$sum"
```

Comment: Fantastic, I had no idea about the `%` operator. I was certain there would be a much simpler solution than mine. Out of curiosity, I have seen the `(( ))` syntax before, but could you explain what it explicitly does?

Incidentally, the usage of `awk` was a relic of a previous approach I tried to this (when I had misinterpreted the question slightly) and was dealing with non-integer numbers which I know bash is not a fan of...

Comment: `for ((...))` is a C-style [arithmetic for loop](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/c_for) and not related to `(( ))` in general. `(( .. ))` by itself is an [arithmetic command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr), the command form of `$((...))` arithmetic expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is almost right except that there are numbers which divide by *both* 3 *and* 5. So you are adding these numbers twice. Hence, you get wrong answer.

Use another loop similar to ones you have and subtract the ones that divide by both 3 and 5 from the result.

Comment: Ah yes, I suspected that may be where the problem arises, I didn't think the question was worded particularly well to make that clear.

I'll see how I get on! Cheers.

Comment: Basically you need a similar loop from 1 to 66 and subtract its sum rom the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A few tips you might find useful:

In bash, you use `let` to give the shell a hint that a variable should be considered a number. All bash variables are strings, but you can do arithmetic on numerical strings. If I say `let i=1` then i is set to 1, but if I say `let i="taco"` then `$i` will be 0, because it couldn't be read as a number. You can achieve a small amount of type-safety when doing mathematical work in the shell.

Bash also has `$((this))` mechanism for doing math! You can check it out yourself: `echo $((2 + 2))` -> `4`, and even more relevant to this problem: `echo $((6 % 3 == 0))` -> `1`

In case you aren't familiar, `%` divides the first number by the second, and gives back the *remainder*; when the remainder is 0, it means that the first is *divisible* by the second! `==` is a test to see if two things are equal, and for logical tests like this 1 represents true and 0 represents false. So I'm testing if 6 is divisible by 3, which it is, and the value I get back is 1.

The test brackets, `[ ... ]` have a "test for equality" flag, `-eq`, which you can use to check if a math expression has a certain value (man test for more details)!

```
$ let i=6
$ echo $((i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0))
1
$ if [ $((i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)) -eq 1 ]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
```

(`||` is another logical test - `$((a || b))` will be 1 (true) when a is true **or** b is true).

Finally, instead of doing this for the number 6, you could do it in a for loop and increment a sum variable every time you find a multiple of 3 or 5:

```
let sum=0
for i in {1..1000}; do
    if [ $((i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)) -eq 1 ]; then
        let sum=$((sum + i))
    fi
done
echo $sum
```

And there you'd have a working solution!

Bash has a lot of nice little tricks, (and a lot more mean ugly tricks), but it's worth learning at least a handful of them to make use of it as a scripting tool.

Comment: Another great solution. Thanks for the explanations!

Comment: I tested your solution, and while I managed to get @that other guy's solution working, your loop throws me a complaint about a missing ]

Comment: That loop actually works just fine with bash, I'm certain you just copied it incorrectly... But that other guy's solution does *look* slightly more efficient, so I'm willing to let bygones be bygones :)

Answer (score 2):

How about creative use of the modulus function & some checks. Then you have just 1 loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1

while [ $i -lt 1000 ]
do 
    if [ $(($i % 3)) -eq 0 ] || [ $(($i % 5)) -eq 0 ]
        then
            sumall=$(($sumall+$i))
    fi
    i=$(($i+1))
done

echo "The sum of both is $sumall"
```

Answer: 233168

Comment: Using `expr` is very portable, but also very slow.  It's also odd when you're using the (obsolescent, undocumented, non-portable) `$[…]` notation for doing arithmetic in the shell.  Using the back-quotes is also generally regarded as a bad idea; it is better to use `$(…)` instead.

Comment: @Norbert, you may be interested to know your answer is 1000 too large ;)

Comment: @JoeHealey : That is bad. Now I inherited your problem: A bug in the code somewhere :): The i=$[$i+1] has to be after my last fi. Updated the code :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Worked with so many different shell scripts that I actually do not keep track of what is undocumented. Updated to the ( ) brackets.

Answer (score 1):

A different solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0
for n in {1..999}; do [ $(((n%5) * (n%3))) -eq 0 ] && sum=$((sum+n)); done
echo $sum
```

The script loops through all numbers below 1000, tests if the product of the number mod 3 and the number mod 5 is 0 (the product of two numbers can only be zero if one of them is zero). If that is the case, it adds the current number to a sum, which is printed out afterwards.

By the way, if I were you I'd include the definition of the `calc` function inside the script, to get a self-contained solution that doesn't need your specific configuration.